# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active after REMOVE object, HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting an error after removing object from database.

Error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:70)
```

I have simple app. I have `EntityManagerFactory` created on start up.

Every time if I want to work with database I create `EntityManager` and after work I close it like this:

Start up:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = ....;
.
.

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
try {
      em.persist(OBJECT TO SAVE); //REALLY NEW OBJECT
} catch (Exception e) {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

So, it's ok, I can save some object to db.

**BUT** If I want to remove item, I am getting an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active.`

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
try {
      em.remove(OBJECT TO REMOVE); //REALLY EXIST IN DB
} catch (Exception e) {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Can you help me with this? I don't know what it is....

**EDIT:** I found some code on google and I tried it:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(em.merge(OBJECT TO REMOVE));
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**And it worked for me!**

Comment: You have to check the state of the transaction before rolling it back.

Comment: @kkkkk Thank you for your replye, check the state using `em.getTransaction().isActive()`? It return `true`

Comment: Try flushing the entity manager before removing the object.

Comment: I try `em.flush()` before `begin` and I get: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`. I try `em.flush()` after `begin` and I get same error `Transaction not active.`.

Comment: @kkkkk look at my post, I append edit section.

Answer (score 1):

Per Javadocs, [entityManager.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) only works with Managed entities and if called on detached entities it will result in IllegalStateException.

So in your case your are calling em.remove on a detaced object and it is resulting in IllegalStateException and your catch block is catching it but your are not printing it. You may want to print the stacktrace in the catch block and this should show the IllegalStateException.

And finally after catching the exception you are still proceeding with commit on an rollbacked transacation and this is resulting in the exception you are seeing.

And the reason why em.remove(em.merge(object)) is working should be clear now. em.merge results in fetching the object from the database and so it becomes a managed entity and calling a remove method on managed entity results in successfully deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a *Repository* using **save** and **remove** methods for your transactions. It is a safer way.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Repository
public abstract class MyEntityRepository implements EntityRepository<MyEntity, Long>, EntityManagerDelegate<MyEntity> {

}
```